# Cut video with ffmpeg in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I execute the command in Ubuntu to cut a video:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -an -ss 00:00:1 -t 00:00:08 -async 1
```

In Windows 10 its work, but not work in Ubuntu.

I receive in Ubuntu the warning:

**Trailing options were found on the commandline.**

and receive the error:

**At least one output file must be specified**

What do I do?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

do:
`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00:01 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 cut.mp4`

just add output file name, in this situation - cut.mp4

Comment: , I try whitout cut.mp4 (output) in windows 10 and work. The Linux not work.

Comment: @PHPDeveloper What's the point of the command without supplying an output file name? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I want to upload a video and shorten the time. From 1 second to 8 seconds.
Always read your answer and topics in StackOverflow. :)

Comment: @PHPDeveloper You'll need to provide an output file name to do that. Not sure how it works in Windows without doing so.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard understand your answer. 
Thanks you very much.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard you have Skype to talk :)

Comment: @PHPDeveloper No, sorry, but you can ask questions at #ffmpeg IRC if you want some sort of live help.